# is it possible to have different research topics for the MSc and PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor

Here is my case, before I studied my master´s degree I managed to write a research paper jointly with a Professor (not from my university) on databases. After that I pursue my master´s degree in CS, but on neural networks rather than databases. The thing is that I would like to do my PhD in databases with the professor I wrote the research paper with. Do you think that I can have problems with the admission committee? I would not like to go to study a PhD without any financial support at all.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why there should be any problem with this whatsoever. It is quite common for students to move around topics, particularly if you are switching between programs or universities. If everybody agrees that you are a good candidate for the position in question, then it shouldn't really matter too much that the topic is not an exact match.

Comment: I agree. Switching fields between MS and PhD is actually quite common in CS. And given that you actually have a paper in databases, it'll probably be **easier** to get into a PhD program to study databases than to stick with neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. As long as your professor agrees. You have to work 4 years+ on the topic so it should be something that you are passionate about.